# Should I backup the ".svn" folders?

Tags: svn, backup, working-copy

I am trying to build a backup plan for my hard-drive, and I wonder whether I need to backup all the ".svn" subfolders?

Note: the repository is not on my computer - my computer contains only a working copy.

Comment: The `.svn` folders should be the same as the repository on the server. So no need for a backup.

Comment: Technically, you do not need to backup .svn folders, because you can always checkout the code from the central repository. Practically, it could be simpler just to backup all the disk as is, so you do not need to remember which repository you need to checkout, for where, what revision etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to backup these [`.svn` folders](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html#idp6875664). Besides of that, you don't really need to backup your working copies since you can always checkout them from the server again.

However, if your working copies are not large -- there is nothing against backing them up as all other data on your system.